# How to switch the activity correctly?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing a POS application with this [device](https://www.mypos.eu/en/devices/smart)(on android 4.4.2) with Nativescript Vue.

I have an SDK for the device, and created a plugin to use it in my application. Everything works fine with it, like printing receipts and getting the device info, but the Payment activity is not working. I've written a function that should open the Activity and on the screen has to appear a payment interface from the device, but nothing happens.

This is my function:

```
payNative() {
        // Build the payment call

        try {
            let amount = new java.lang.Double('13.87');
            let payment = this.$mypos.MyPOSPayment.builder()
            // Mandatory parameters
                .productAmount(amount)
                .currency(this.$mypos.Currency.EUR)
                // Foreign transaction ID. Maximum length: 128 characters
                .foreignTransactionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();

            let context = application.android.context;
            // Start the transaction
            // this.$mypos.MyPOSAPI.openPaymentActivity(context, payment, 1);

            let MyPOSUtil = this.$mypos.MyPOSUtil;
            let myposIntent;

            if (payment.isMotoTransaction()) {
                console.log('motoo');
                myposIntent = new android.content.Intent(MyPOSUtil.PAYMENT_CORE_ENTRY_POINT_MOTO_INTENT);
                console.log(myposIntent);
            } else if (payment.isGiftCardTransaction()) {
                console.log('giftt');
                myposIntent = new android.content.Intent(MyPOSUtil.PAYMENT_CORE_ENTRY_POINT_GIFTCARD_INTENT);
                console.log(myposIntent);
            } else {
                myposIntent = new android.content.Intent(MyPOSUtil.PAYMENT_CORE_ENTRY_POINT_INTENT);
                console.log('normalll');
                console.log(myposIntent);
            }

            let skipConfirmationScreen = false;

            console.log('*************** ++++++++++++++ ******************');
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSACTION_REQUEST_CODE', MyPOSUtil.TRANSACTION_TYPE_PAYMENT);
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT', new java.lang.Double(payment.getProductAmount()));
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSACTION_TIP_AMOUNT', new java.lang.Double(payment.getTipAmount()));
            console.log('INTENT_SKIP_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN', skipConfirmationScreen);
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSFER_TIPS_ENABLED', payment.isTippingModeEnabled());
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY', payment.getCurrency().toString());
            console.log('INTENT_TRANSACTION_FOREIGN_TRANSACTION_ID', payment.getForeignTransactionId());
            console.log('INTENT_PRINT_MERCHANT_RECEIPT', payment.getPrintMerchantReceipt());
            console.log('INTENT_PRINT_CUSTOMER_RECEIPT', payment.getPrintCustomerReceipt());
            console.log('INTENT_OPERATOR_CODE', payment.getOperatorCode());
            console.log('INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER', payment.getReferenceNumber());
            console.log('INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER_TYPE', payment.getReferenceType());
            console.log('INTENT_MOTO_PASSWORD', payment.getMotoPassword());
            console.log('*************** ++++++++++++++ ******************');

            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSACTION_REQUEST_CODE, MyPOSUtil.TRANSACTION_TYPE_PAYMENT);
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, new java.lang.Double(payment.getProductAmount()));
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSACTION_TIP_AMOUNT, new java.lang.Double(payment.getTipAmount()));
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_SKIP_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN, skipConfirmationScreen);
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSFER_TIPS_ENABLED, payment.isTippingModeEnabled());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY, payment.getCurrency().toString());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_TRANSACTION_FOREIGN_TRANSACTION_ID, payment.getForeignTransactionId());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_PRINT_MERCHANT_RECEIPT, payment.getPrintMerchantReceipt());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_PRINT_CUSTOMER_RECEIPT, payment.getPrintCustomerReceipt());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_OPERATOR_CODE, payment.getOperatorCode());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER, payment.getReferenceNumber());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER_TYPE, payment.getReferenceType());
            myposIntent.putExtra(MyPOSUtil.INTENT_MOTO_PASSWORD, payment.getMotoPassword());

            console.log(myposIntent);

            application.android.foregroundActivity.startActivityForResult(myposIntent, 1);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

When I execute it, this is the live log from the device (adb logcat)

```
I/JS      ( 6712): '*************** ++++++++++++++ ******************'
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSACTION_REQUEST_CODE' 101
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT' {}
D/alsa_pcm(  144): pcm_open:,sparams.stop_threshold:1540, config->stop_threshold:0
V/audio_hw_primary(  144): do not use out resampler
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSACTION_TIP_AMOUNT' {}
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_SKIP_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN' false
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSFER_TIPS_ENABLED' false
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY' 'EUR'
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_TRANSACTION_FOREIGN_TRANSACTION_ID' '4b3d6780-b87e-4633-bf0f-76a43f963847'
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_PRINT_MERCHANT_RECEIPT' 0
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_PRINT_CUSTOMER_RECEIPT' 0
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_OPERATOR_CODE' null
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER' null
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_REFERENCE_NUMBER_TYPE' 0
I/JS      ( 6712): 'INTENT_MOTO_PASSWORD' null
I/JS      ( 6712): '*************** ++++++++++++++ ******************'
I/JS      ( 6712): {}
W/DeviceManager(  488): ++++++++++switch == true
E/DeviceManager(  488): +++switch = true   action=com.mypos.transaction.START_TRANSACTION   packageName=   callingPackage=sellfer.pos   className=
W/PAXDROID/PaxCustomerManager(  488): Runtime: /data/app/com.mypos-2.apk is in the whitelist, no need to verify it at run time.
W/ActivityManager(  488): startActivityMayWait() packageName = com.mypos, appSourcePath = /data/app/com.mypos-2.apk
I/ActivityManager(  488): START u0 {act=com.mypos.transaction.START_TRANSACTION cmp=com.mypos/.ui.activity.PaymentActivity (has extras)} from pid 6712
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:home_stack_is_frant_stack = false
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:mService.mBooting = false
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:home_stack_is_frant_stack = false
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:mService.mBooting = false
D/ConnectivityService(  488): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10058, uidRules=0)
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.service.IppStub( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.065 CLIENT: 6.5
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.service.IppStub( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.066 SERVICE: 6.6
D/ipps    ( 1600): file>>>/storage/emulated/0/neptune/app.db
D/ipps    ( 1600): insert Db>>>SQLiteDatabase: /storage/emulated/0/neptune/app.db
D/ipps    ( 1600): after insert Db>>>0
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.service.IppStub( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.110 CLIENT: 6.5
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.service.IppStub( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.112 SERVICE: 6.6
D/ipps    ( 1600): file>>>/storage/emulated/0/neptune/app.db
D/ipps    ( 1600): insert Db>>>SQLiteDatabase: /storage/emulated/0/neptune/app.db
D/ipps    ( 1600): after insert Db>>>0
E/SpdevServerThread(  771): msg from sp
E/SpdevServerThread(  771): get a message msg.cmd=3
E/SpdevServerThread(  771): sp icon
E/SpdevServerThread(  771): subcmd is:0x04
E/SpdevServerThread(  771): msg is:0x00
W/ContextImpl(  771): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1214 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:372 com.pax.daemon.observer.ServerService$2.onIconEvent:498 com.pax.daemon.server.SpdevServerThread.notifyIconStatusObserver:268 com.pax.daemon.server.SpdevServerThread.msg_handler:67
E/IcCardStatusReceive(  668): onReceive=com.pax.intent.action.ICCSTATUS
W/InputMethodManagerService(  488): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@420ab808 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@422039d8
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:home_stack_is_frant_stack = false
E/ActivityManager(  488): hbc:mService.mBooting = false
D/ConnectivityService(  488): onUidRulesChanged(uid=10058, uidRules=0)
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.manager.Terminal( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.473 HOLDED BY=, RECENT IS=1600, HOLDER IS RECENT=false
D/IPP_IPPS_com.pax.ipp.manager.Terminal( 1501): 01-17 03:10:59.474 HAS RELEASED=true
D/IPP_IPPI_com.pax.ippi.impl.NeptuneUser( 1600): 01-17 03:10:59.477 unRegister
D/DeviceManagerService(  488): setNavigationBarInvisible: invisible=false
W/DeviceManagerService(  488): setBackKeyDisable disable = false
D/DeviceManagerService(  488): setHomeKeyDisable disable=false
D/DeviceManagerService(  488): setRecentKeyDisable disable=false
D/audio_hw_primary(  144): out_standby
D/BatteryService(  488): huangbc ... shutdownIfBatteryNotPresent call ...
D/BatteryService(  488): huangbc ... shutdownIfBatteryNotPresent call ...
D/PowerManagerService(  488): mHoldBootFastWakeLock = true
I/PowerUI (  546): mIntentReceiver action=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
E/PaxSmartDeviceManagerService(  668): mBatteryReceiver=BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
D/ConnectivityService(  488): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
D/ConnectivityService(  488): Done.
D/ConnectivityService(  488): Setting timer for 30seconds
D/AlarmManager(  488): hbc ... set alarm:package =  android, type = 3, triggerAtTime = 4792556, windowLength = -1, interval = 0
E/PaxSmartDeviceManagerService(  668): MyTimerTask------
```

What should happen is to switch to device's Payment activity, but nothing happens on the screen.

This part of the log hints me that my function actually trying to do the thing, but something is wrong, but I'm new with Nativescript and android.

```
W/DeviceManager(  488): ++++++++++switch == true
E/DeviceManager(  488): +++switch = true   action=com.mypos.transaction.START_TRANSACTION   packageName=   callingPackage=sellfer.pos   className=
W/PAXDROID/PaxCustomerManager(  488): Runtime: /data/app/com.mypos-2.apk is in the whitelist, no need to verify it at run time.
W/ActivityManager(  488): startActivityMayWait() packageName = com.mypos, appSourcePath = /data/app/com.mypos-2.apk
I/ActivityManager(  488): START u0 {act=com.mypos.transaction.START_TRANSACTION cmp=com.mypos/.ui.activity.PaymentActivity (has extras)} from pid 6712
```

Comment: What is the value of `MyPOSUtil.PAYMENT_CORE_ENTRY_POINT_MOTO_INTENT`? You usually pass in the Activity Class that needs to be started in the constructor of Intent.

Comment: We actually never entering the first if(), in my example we are entering the last else MyPOSUtil.PAYMENT_CORE_ENTRY_POINT_INTEN. The value of this is : com.mypos.transaction.START_TRANSACTION

Comment: In that case, I believe it's an Action. Until your activity has registered for that particular action in your manifest, it won't appear. The easiest way is usually to pass the Activity class directly. Do they have a official docs for Android, your SDK.

Comment: This is the official repo and docs. https://github.com/developermypos/myPOS-Smart-SDK . I will look for something on the manifest.